# How to use graph_from_place() function

Tags: graph, networkx

I installed all the packages and make the following code work, but then did sth now it doesn't work.

```
import osmnx as ox
place_name = "Kamppi, Helsinki, Finland"
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name)
type(graph)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(graph)
plt.tight_layout()
```

give the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'MultiDiGraph'
```

Comment: Can you check which version of NetworkX you are using ?

Comment: Hi. Version 2.3 installed.

Comment: I just ran your code snippet on my computer, and it executed fine without error.

Comment: @gboeing Which version do you have? Maybe I should install that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I had version 2.3 and uninstalled the module `networkx` using

```
pip3 uninstall networkx
```

Then install a previous version using

```
pip3 install networkx==2.0
```

Now it works. :)